# Visual Studio App Centre - Xamarin Android Crash Reporting not working

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I've been using the MS App-Centre for a while now and have been using it collect crash and error analtycs.

After some recent changes the Crash reporting is no longer working, it's failing itself with the error:

```
Cannot retrieve package info
E/AppCenter(28376): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager 

android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
at com.microsoft.appcenter.utils.DeviceInfoHelper.getDeviceInfo(DeviceInfoHelper.java:50)
at com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.utils.ErrorLogHelper.createErrorLog(ErrorLogHelper.java:123)
at com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:925)
at com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.WrapperSdkExceptionManager.saveWrapperException(WrapperSdkExceptionManager.java:50)
```

Having looked on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-Android/blob/287bcdfe89ea5f1ec5eebb76adb1201a9d4a8216/sdk/appcenter/src/main/java/com/microsoft/appcenter/utils/DeviceInfoHelper.java) my best guess is that for some reason Application.Context is null when they call this method.  The only thing that I've changed recently (that I think could be relevant) is the Application Target SDK moved from 21 to 27.  I carry out similar operations in other parts of the app for my own logging etc and it seems to be working.

Error reporting and other analytics all seem to be working fine, it's just the uncaught crashes.

Has anyone seen this issue or similar?

Comment: Can you enable verbose logging using `AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose` before `AppCenter.start` then share all the logs having `AppCenter` tag prefix from start of app to crash? You can upload logs by creating a ticket on our support center at https://appcenter.ms using the chat button. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to me failing to update all the AppCentre packages across all the projects that referenced it in the solution to the same version.  After sending the support center @ appcenter.ms some logs they spotted it.  I swore I consolidated them all when I first noticed the crash logs weren't going up but I had actually missed one somehow.  Having consolidated them all I had to delete my bin and obj directories and then the crash analytics worked again.